# How to prompt the user to input information and then print results using the keyboard class method?

Tags: java, string, keyboard, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java and working on a Java Assignment using strings, keyboard class method, and scanner. I am not exactly sure which to use in different circumstances. I have to prompt the user to input their city and state and have to print out a result that prints out their state in uppercase, city in lowercase, and then state again in upper case.  The question for the assignment is here:

Declare two new variables city and state of type String. Add statements to the program to prompt the user to enter their hometown -- the city and the state. Read in the results using the appropriate **Keyboard class method**. Then using **String class methods** create and print a new string that consists of the state name (all in uppercase letters) followed by the city name (all in lowercase letters) followed again by the state name (uppercase). So, if the user enters Lilesville for the city and North Carolina for the state, the program should create and print the string:
 NORTH CAROLINAlilesvilleNORTH CAROLINA

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;



int city, state;
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println ("Enter your hometown city:");
city = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println ("Enter your hometown state:");
state = scan.nextInt();
```

When I run the program, I type in the city and then I receive a run-time error. The compiler says:

"java.util.InputMismatchException:
null (in java.util.Scanner)"

In conclusion, The final question that I am asking is how to read in the results using the Keyboard class method and how to print something like "NORTH CAROLINAlilesvilleNORTH CAROLINA"(EX) using the string class method.
I am sorry if you are confused by anything that I have stated and I appreciate all the help that is involved. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Change `int` to `String`. Your `Scanner` object is looking for Integers but your giving it Strings.

Answer (score 2):

MisMatch exception which you are getting is because you are using incorrect datatype. state and city is declared as int but you are entering the name.

So instead of int ,declare state and city as string and use scan.nextLine() instead of scan.nextInt().

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. How do I initialize a string after I declare it? How would my code look when declaring city and state? How would I read in the results and with which keyboard class method? Thanks again for your help. Sorry for the rapid amount of questions.

Comment: Actually I do not think I need to initialize because when I compiled it, it worked fine. I just do not know how to return STATEcitySTATE using string class methods.